# File Transfer over SSH connection

Tags: ssh, terminal, file-transfer

I need to transfer (copy) files from my local computer (unix) to a remote computer host (linux) while I have established a SSH connection to the remote computer.

After connecting using SSH, and while under this very same SSH connection to the remote host, what command in the terminal do I use to transfer (copy/sync) files to that remote host from my local computer?

I know about 'scp', 'sftp' and 'rsync' file transfers but these are used OUT of the SSH connection, independently correct?...So, I want to be able to run a command that copies the files under that secure SSH connection.

Could I use 'scp', 'sftp', 'ftp' , or 'rsync' commands under the running SSH connection, and if so HOW?

Thanks!

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking this as the Superuser exchange (http://superuser.com), or the Unix and Linux exchange (http://unix.stackexchange.com)  It's off topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: This might be the answer you are actually wanting to know about: https://askubuntu.com/questions/13382/download-a-file-over-an-active-ssh-session/13586#13586

scp, sftp, etc., create their own SSH connection unless they are tunneled through a certain port that has already been opened. This is true anytime they are run from the command line, whether or not that command line is part of an existing SSH session. Tunneling data is inefficient and no more secure than an independent SSH connection except where you are trying to relay between servers to hide your own address.

To do what you want, you need to set up your local computer to allow SSH access. Then you can simply do things like "scp -P 4321 yourUserName@yourlocalhostsexternalhostname:path/to/file.txt ./" in order to copy a file to your server at the same time that you are logged in to your server.

It is a pain to type that command out all the time, and I prefer to work in the command line on my local Unix computer and synchronize just the current working directory to wherever it belongs on the server. I am including my program to do this (it is only designed for when you are going to be the one running it--there are lots of insecure lines that trust the user's input far too much).

This program is so easy to use that I have never used anything else to transfer files that I am working on my local computer to my live webserver, for several years. And when I am working for others, I always miss this program.

In order to use this program, you have to create a file ".root" within the current directory or any parent directory. The ".root" file specifies where on the server that root directory belongs. This way, my program can find exactly where any subdirectory of that root directory belongs. And it greatly multiplies the efficiency of rsync, because instead of rsyncing through my whole web site, it simply rsyncs the part of the website that I am working on at that instant.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# cpwd
# make sure it is in your path
$flagjpeg = "--exclude '*.JPG'";
my $J = shift;
$flagjpeg = "" if $J eq 'JPG';
$n = 10;
$wd = '';
while (! -f '.root') {
$pwd = `pwd | xargs basename`;
chomp $pwd;
$wd = "$pwd/$wd";
chdir('..');
last if $n-- < 1;
}

# chop $wd;

if (! -f '.root') {
    print "No root found!\n";
    exit;
}
$root = `head -1 .root`;
chomp $root;
@cmds = ($root =~ m/(\S+)/g);
$root = pop(@cmds);
$source = "$wd" || './';
$dest = "$root/$source";

print "copy '@cmds' '$source' (to) '$dest'\n";

my $cmd = "(rsync @cmds -vv --max-size=1208KiB $flagjpeg --exclude '*.ezip' --exclude '*.tgz' --exclude '*.gz' -C -avz $source $dest 2>&1) > /tmp/cpwd.log";
chomp(my $mypwd = `pwd`);
my $cmdlarge = "cd '$mypwd'; (rsync @cmds -vv $flagjpeg --exclude '*.ezip' --exclude '*.tgz' --exclude '*.gz' -C -avz $source $dest 2>&1) > /tmp/cpwd.log";

print "$cmd\n$cmdlarge\n\n";

# exit;

system($cmd);

system("grep -e 'over max-size' -e 'sender finished' /tmp/cpwd.log");
system("tail -4 /tmp/cpwd.log | head -3");
```

Example of a ".root" file:

```
$ cat .root
myname@server.net:www
```

Example of a ".root" file with extra flags:

```
$ cat .root
 -e 'ssh -p 4321 -C' yourname@host2468.hosthosthost.com:www
```

Once the "cpwd" program is in your path and the ".root" file is created somewhere in the current or parent directory, all you need to do is work on your website and go to the command line (Ctrl-Z comes to mind) and type

```
$ cpwd
```

in order to synchronize everything within the working directory to your website as specified in the .root file.

Note that for safety cpwd will not create more than one level of non-existing directories, just in case you goof up your ".root" file and try to replicate your entire website inside of a subdirectory of your webserver by accident.